# Dynamically print or assign the value to html from arraylist in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a arraylist I have a key starting from hours0 to hours6
I want to print the value of that array list by keeping this hours in for loop.

```
if(checkTime.length != 0){
    for(var i=0; i<checkTime.length; i++){
        for(var j=0; j<7; j++){
            if(checkTime[i].hours+j != 0){

                $('#Hours'+j+'').val(checkTime[i].hours+''+j); //I need to get the value of checkTime[i].hours0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

checkTime object:

```
var checkTime = [{"timeid":670122,"typeofhours":"Absence","daystracked":"Paternity_Leave","paycategory":0,"requeststatus":"NA","dateentered":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":25},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"approveddate":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":25},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"secondapproverpmfkey":"","secondapproveddate":{"date":{"year":1900,"month":1,"day":1},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"thirdapproverpmfkey":"","thirdapproveddate":{"date":{"year":1900,"month":1,"day":1},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"date0":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":23},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"date1":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":24},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"date2":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":25},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"date3":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":26},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"date4":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":27},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"date5":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":28},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"date6":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":29},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"hours0":0,"hours1":0,"hours2":7.5,"hours3":7.5,"hours4":0,"hours5":0,"hours6":0,"enteredhours":15,"standardhours":37.5,"hourly_rt":0,"lastupdated":{"date":{"year":2017,"month":4,"day":25},"time":{"hour":0,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}},"senttopayroll":"NO","pi_emplid":"","sendnow":"NO","sentreminder":0,"countrycode":"GB ","payroll_code":"INT","ninetydays":"NO ","empcomments":""}]
```

I want to concatenate the hours+j as hours0 to print or assign.

Can anybody suggest?

Comment: can you please share the arraylist

Comment: I have re-modified the snippet... @guest271314

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your question is not at all clear bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the attribute name of an JSON object like the following.

`JSONObject['attributename']`

As you have an array you need to access `checkTime[index]['attributename']`

```
if(checkTime.length != 0){
   for(var i=0; i<checkTime.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<7; j++){
        if(checkTime[i]['hours'+j] != 0){
            $('#Hours'+j+'').val(checkTime[i]['hours'+j]); //I need to get the value of checkTime[i].hours0
        }
     } 
    }      
  }
```